# Mysql: connect to db is lost after Include()

Tags: php, mysql

my calendar script works perfectly fine until I include it into my template. html within events.php is formatted fine but the connection to the database is not processed resulting in the errors you see below. Why is this happening, connection being lost/not processed?

```
<?php include ROOT . '/files/cal/events.php';?>
```

**Errors:**

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/social/public_html/files/cal/smoothcalendar.php on line 19

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/social/public_html/files/cal/smoothcalendar.php on line 21

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/social/public_html/files/cal/smoothcalendar.php on line 195

Could not run query: 
Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/social/public_html/files/cal/smoothcalendar.php on line 38

**smoothcalendar.php**

```
<?php
$server   = "localhost";
$username = "****"; 
$password = "****";
$dbname   = "***_socialdb";

class SmoothCalendar {

    private $options = null,
            $get,
            $post;

    private $connection;

    function __construct($options) 
    {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($GLOBALS["server"  ],
                                          $GLOBALS["username"],
                                          $GLOBALS["password"]);

        mysql_select_db($GLOBALS["dbname"],$this->connection);
```

Comment: I recommend not using $GLOBALS

Comment: @J.Bruni i switched the $GLOBALS variable to $conn and still same error

Comment: @acctan: Have you defined it in the same scope you are using the variable? Please read the introduction of this manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: volunteer editors, PLEASE do not format **error messages** as the **code**, making them harder to read. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your `include` inside a function or something else, i.e., **not** in the global context. That's why your variables can't be reached using the $GLOBALS array... they're not global.

This should work:

```
<?php

class SmoothCalendar {

    private $options = null,
            $get,
            $post;

    private $connection;

    private $server   = "localhost";
    private $username = "****"; 
    private $password = "****";
    private $dbname   = "***_socialdb";

    function __construct($options) 
    {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->server,
                                          $this->username,
                                          $this->password);

        mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $this->connection);
```